# Pulling Amazon Rating Stars and Rating Count with Product Advertising API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I understand this has been asked before. I also understand there is probably a way to scrape this. What I am after here is different than what has already been asked (I believe).

What I am after is being able to pull just the stars, and the amount of reviews for a given product WITHOUT breaking the TOS of Amazon.

I do not want to display all of the reviews and such that are inside of the iframe that they let you use. I am able to display the iframe, but I don't need to display that much information. So to be clear, I just want the Stars and the # of reviews (the average customer review, and # of reviews).

If you want to go the extra mile and tell me how, I'd really appreciate knowing how via PHP! If this is against the TOS, that's all Id really need to know. If it is, I'd love it if you could provide me a link to where it says that it IS against the TOS.

Thanks for any and all help! It's always appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party. As of 2020-09-21, you can get rating stars and reviews count by call the **GetItems** endpoint of Amazon Product Advertising API V5. Enter an ASIN you would like to look up and have **CustomerReviews** resource checked.

[API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjAt.png)

Do note Amazon changes the data points they would like to expose through API from time to time. They might not be available some day in the future.

**[Update as of 2021 September]**
What I realized is that some foreign marketplaces might don't have rating and reviews returned through API. As of now, data is available at US and CA marketplaces. But it is not available in UK.

Comment: Under what resource CustomerReviews appear? It's under Offers? ItemInfo?

Comment: FYI, The actual resource you need to add is "   "CustomerReviews.Count",
                    "CustomerReviews.StarRating""

Comment: It is present as a resource on scratchpad but not working anymore, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the TOS, but to do that in php, if there is no official api, you can use simple_html_dom: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

```
<?php
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); 
include './simple_html_dom.php';

//Your product amazon's url
$url = 'https://www.amazon.com/SOL-REPUBLIC-1112-31-Headphones-1-Button/dp/B00COOVLMQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=fiona-hardware&ie=UTF8&qid=1470197678&sr=8-1&keywords=sol+republic';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$review_section = $html->find('#averageCustomerReviews',0);
$stars = $review_section->find('#reviewStarsLinkedCustomerReviews',0)->plaintext;
preg_match('/\d+\.{0,1}\d*/',$stars,$match);
echo "Stars: ".$match[0]; //Shoud be stars
echo "<br />";
$reviews = $review_section->find('#acrCustomerReviewText',0)->plaintext;
preg_match('/\d+/',$reviews,$match);
echo "Reviews: ".$match[0] //Shoud be reviews number
?>
```

I actually tried and it works for me.

Comment: showing `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object` I have downloaded `simple_html_dom`

Comment: @fool I tested again and I still get the stars and rating... Check your inclusion of `simple_html_dom` and required functions availability such as `file_get_contents`. I tested this script only on amazon.com pages, and it works just on page where number of reviews and stars are declared near the title. EDIT: Just tried on amazon.it, works as well.

Comment: I think this is not legal way for pulling AWS average star ratings, because they are did not provided any response group or elements for this, only provided iframe url

Comment: I've tried scraping these sorts of things several times, eventually after a handful of calls you'll start getting canned responses from Amazon saying that you should utilize their API to get data - of course they do not offer an endpoint for getting reviews outside of product advertising API and you have to sign up for an account which will ultimately be closed if you do not refer so many qualifying purchases to Amazon (which is the point of the product advertising API).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do from PAPI. You either need to scrape it yourself or use other third party API. We use the [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) API from RapidAPI, it supports price/rating/review count fetching for up to 1000 products in a single request.